# Prove $Sp(1)$ homeomorphic to $S^3$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Given Hamilton quaternions  $\mathbb{H} = \{a+bi+cj+dk\mid a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}\}$ with subgroup $Sp(1) = \{x\in\mathbb{H}\mid \|x\| = 1\}$.

Since we can identify $\mathbb{H}$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$,now define subspace topology on $Sp(1)$.

Prove given embedding $i:Sp(1)\to \mathbb{R}^4$, $Sp(1)$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$.

we know restriction of embedding is also continuous so we have continuous bijection:$i':Sp(1)\to i(Sp(1)) = S^3$

The problem here how to show its inverse is also continuous.It seems prove $Sp(1)$ is compact is sufficient.

Is bounded since $Sp(1)$ has norm 1,and it's level set so it's closed,is my proof correct?

By the way,embedding $i':X\to i(X)$ is not homeomorphism in general,correct?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are just giving $\mathbb H$ the topology of $\mathbb R^4$ by the identification, and $Sp(1)$ is sent to $\mathbb S^3$. So by your definition it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^3$.

Comment: @Arctic Char Oh,do you mean given homeomorphism,$\psi: \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{R}^4$, the restriction on $Sp(1) \to S^3$ is also homeomorphism?

Comment: Also, the letter $p$ is not in the subscript. It's $Sp(1)$, not $S_p(1)$. Just like $SU(2)$, not $S_u(2)$.

Comment: Yes @yi_li ${}{}$

Comment: And to answer your last question, when we say a mapping $f$ is an embedding, it is by definition that $f : X\to f(X)$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Arctic Char  ok,thanks

Comment: Given $x=a+bi+cj+dk\in\mathbb{H}$ in the unit circle $Sp(1),$ that is $\|x\| = 1,$ means $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1.$ This clearly defines a bijection $Sp(1)\to S^3.$ Now you just need to show this map is continuous (since $Sp(1)$ is compact and $S^3$ is Hausdorff). BTW, your last line is confusing as there is no $X$ mentioned in the body.

Comment: @Bumblebee thanks,I mean the general case, that is for any $X$ as topological space, dose embedding always homeomorphic to its image? By the definition, it must homeomorphic to its image.So this question have been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same identification $I$ that maps $a + bi + cj + dk\in \Bbb H$ to $(a,b,c,d) \in \Bbb R^4$ (which is by definition a homeomorphism, as this is how you give $\Bbb H$ its topology, and which preserves norm too, so that $\textrm{Sp}(1)$ is mapped exactly to $\Bbb S^3 \subseteq \Bbb R^4$ and this means that the restriction of $I$ to $\textrm{Sp}(1)$ in the domain and $\Bbb S^3$ in the codomain, is a homeomorphism too. Nothing to with compactness: if $h: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism between spaces, then for all $A \subseteq X$, $h\restriction_A: A \to h[A]$ is also a homeomorphism.